# Quadratic form and orthogonality

Tags: quadratic-forms, orthogonal-matrices

If the equation $\textbf{x}^T \textbf{x} = \textbf{x}^T M \textbf{x}$ is true for all $\textbf{x}$ and a matrix M in a euclidian vector space, does that imply that M is an orthogonal matrix? And if so, which theorem does that follow from? Unfortunately I could not find anything answering this specific question.

Comment: No, if   you intend $M$  to be symmetric, it must be the identity matrix.

Comment: Also, a non-symmetric counterexample:$$M=\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1}.$$